# LDAP Active directory group based authentication in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, ldap

I am not able to perform LDAP Active directory group based authentication in .Net Core 2.0

Please provide me any solution for .Net core 2.0

Comment: Which web server you're using - Kestrel or Http.Sys or IIS?

Comment: I am using IIS web server for my application

Comment: See if this helps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1